# Indexing into arrays of arbitrary rank in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, iteration, padding, pinning

I need to iterate over an array of arbitrary rank. This is for both reading and writing, so `GetEnumerator` will not work.

`Array.SetValue(object, int)` doesn't work on multidimensional arrays.
`Array.SetValue(object, params int[])` would require excessive arithmetic for iterating through the multidimensional space. It would also require dynamic invocation to get around the `params` part of the signature.

I'm tempted to pin the array and iterate over it with a pointer, but I can't find any documentation that says that multidimensional arrays are guaranteed to be contiguous. If they have padding at the end of a dimension then that won't work. I'd also prefer to avoid unsafe code.

Is there an easy way to sequentially address a multidimensional array using only a single index?

Comment: I see no error in using "unsafe" code. It's safe to use pointers when you actually know what you are doing and it's a viable and efficient solution.

Comment: Btw it's perfectly valid to pass an `int[]` where a `params int[]` is expected.

Comment: @dtb, you appear to be correct on both syntax points. I never knew you could directly pass an array to a params array parameter.

Comment: @Mikael Svenson, I agree that unsafe code is not to be feared, but I also think it should be avoided if there is an equivalent safe solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Multidimensional arrays are guaranteed to be contiguous. From ECMA-335:

> Array elements shall be laid out within the array object in row-major order (i.e., the elements associated with the rightmost array dimension **shall be laid out contiguously** from lowest to highest index).

So this works:

```
int[,,,] array = new int[10, 10, 10, 10];

fixed (int* ptr = array)
{
    ptr[10] = 42;
}

int result = array[0, 0, 1, 0];  // == 42
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for and gives me a good fall-back implementation. BTW, I think your code chokes on 'int* ptr = array', but the idea is sound.

Comment: @Kennet Belenky: I've just double-checked and the code works perfectly well as is. Of course, a solution involving unsafe code doesn't help if you want to avoid unsafe code, but I fear there is no other solution that doesn't come with a lot of (unnecessary) overhead (such as recursively iterating through all dimensions).

Comment: ... however it turns out that pinning only works if the array contains primitive value types. I didn't mention this in the original question, but the array I'm trying to address also has an arbitrary ElementType, and may contain structs, reference types or boxed value types. I guess I have to resort to using an indexing array.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Rank` and `GetUpperBound` property/method to create an indices array that you can pass to the array's `SetValue` and `GetValue` methods:

```
int[] Indices(Array a, int idx)
{
    var indices = new int[a.Rank];

    for (var i = 0; i < a.Rank; i++)
    {
        var div = 1;

        for (var j = i + 1; j < a.Rank; j++)
        {
            div *= a.GetLength(j);
        }

        indices[i] = a.GetLowerBound(i) + idx / div % a.GetLength(i);
    }

    return indices;
}
```

..and use it like so:

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
{
    var indices = Indices(array, i);
    array.SetValue(i, indices);
    var val = array.GetValue(indices);
}
```

Comment: Yes, that would be the excessive arithmetic I was talking about. You would also need to use Array.GetLowerBound, not just Array.GetUpperBound.

Comment: @kennet Actually, we *don't* need `Array.GetUpperBound`, just saw the `Array.GetLength` method :)

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you could join them all into the a single temporary collection, and just iterate over that.

Comment: Easy enough, I'll just use GetEnumerator to address everything in the array. The problem is that I also have to write at various points in the array, and GetEnumerator will fail for that.