# Pass multi -  dimensional array from managed code to unmanaged code

Tags: c#, c++, marshalling, dllimport

I would like to do the following:

1. Create three dimesinal array in c# code like this:

   ```
   var myArray = new short[x,y,z];
   UnanagedFunction(myArray);
   ```
2. Pass it to unmanaged code (c++) like this:

   ```
   void UnmanagedFunction(short*** myArray)
   {
       short first = myArray[0][0][0];
   }
   ```

**UPDATED**
When I try the following code I have runtime error:

> Attempted to read or write to protected memory.

Thank you!!!

Comment: You can't write code like that in C++.

Comment: the first part of code is in c# the second is in c++ and i tried it now compiler allows me the c++ code

Comment: Maybe you can change your code to an array of triples.

Comment: @Simon, how is an array of triples going to help? Do you mean quadruples (x, y, z and the value)?

Comment: I think the problem is that you have `short[,,]` (which doesn't have  C++ equivalent), but you treat it as `short[][][]`.

Comment: But there is no marshaling support for nested (short[][][]) arrays

Comment: You can't even do that in pure C++. You must write all-but-one dimensions on the function prototype. Read this: http://c-faq.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx9a.html (so for example `void UnmanagedFunction(short myArray[][10][10]`) )

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
IntPtr Array3DToIntPtr(short[, ,] Val)
        {
            IntPtr ret = Marshal.AllocHGlobal((Val.GetLength(0) + Val.GetLength(1) + Val.GetLength(2)) * sizeof(short));

            int offset = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < Val.GetLength(0); i++)
            {

                for (int j = 0; j < Val.GetLength(1); j++)
                {
                    for (int k = 0; k < Val.GetLength(2); k++)
                    {
                        Marshal.WriteInt16(ret,offset, Val[i, j, k]);
                        offset += sizeof(short);


                    }
                }
            }

            return ret;
        }
```

This has been tested and it works, the only limitation is that you have to call `Marshal.FreeHGlobal` on the array pointer when you are done with it or you will get a memory leak, I would also suggest that you change your c++ function so that it accepts the array dimensions or you will only be able to use 3d arrays of specific size

Answer (score 2):

I'm writing it in pure C#, but if you take away the `unsafe static` from `Func`, the `Func` should work in C/C++. Be aware that I'm note sure sure it's ok ok to write this :-)
I'm using this [Indexing into arrays of arbitrary rank in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3408655/indexing-into-arrays-of-arbitrary-rank-in-c/3408809#3408809)

```
static unsafe void Main(string[] args) {
    var myArray = new short[5, 10, 20];

    short z = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < myArray.GetLength(0); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < myArray.GetLength(1); j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < myArray.GetLength(2); k++) {
                myArray[i, j, k] = z;
                z++;
            }
        }
    }

    // myArray[1, 2, 3] == 243

    fixed (short* ptr = myArray) {
        Func(ptr, myArray.GetLength(0), myArray.GetLength(1), myArray.GetLength(2));
    }
}

// To convert to C/C++ take away the static unsafe
static unsafe void Func(short* myArray, int size1, int size2, int size3) {
    int x = 1, y = 2, z = 3;
    int el = myArray[x * size2 * size3 + y * size3 + z]; // el == 243
}
```