# IntPtr to three dimensional array

Tags: c#, c++, arrays, pinvoke, intptr

I am using a C++ dll into my C# project. Using pInvoke (Platform Invoke).

My C++ code returns a double***, and the C# function returns a IntPtr.

I have the dimensions of the matrix on both sides, they are just not constant.

On C# side I have:

```
[DllImport("mylib.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr GetMatrix(int width, int height, int depth);
```

And on C++ side I have:

```
extern "C" {
    __declspec(dllexport) double*** GetMatrix(int width, int height, int depth) {
        // do stuff
        return matrix;
    }
}
```

Now I need to convert this IntPtr to a double[,,], but, I have no idea how to do that.

Basicaly I need the oposite to the answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7153521/pass-multi-dimensional-array-from-managed-code-to-unmanaged-code/7186800#7186800).

Comment: You need to know more. It's not enough to know the type. You also need to know the dimensions.

Comment: I do know the dimensions in both sides, they are just not constant. I edited the question...

Comment: I resolved this, instead of returning the whole matrix, I'm just returning a single double. So yeah, I'm invoking the DLL multiple times. At least the values come correct. But my question still has no solution...

Comment: What is missing in the question?

Comment: Description of how you obtain the dimensions for a start

Comment: I edited the question. The user provides the dimensions to the GetMatrix function on C# side. What else do you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never tried this with these kinds of arrays, but this first solution may work and I'm lead to believe so by [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z6cfh6e6(v=vs.100).aspx):

(Note this only works if you can change the function definition on the C# side) In your C# function, change your `IntPtr` parameter to a `double[,,]` parameter and add this MarshalAs attribute to it, similar to how the above MSDN article does it.

```
[DllImport("FooBar.dll")]
extern void Foo([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeConst=**YOUR ARRAY SIZE HERE**)] double[,,] bar);
```

This also assumes that you have a constant-sized array, and I'm not sure how this would exactly work with a 3d array, but if you'd like to investigate this type of solution further, here's the full documentation for [MarshalAsAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshalasattribute(v=vs.100).aspx).

---

The other solution is very similar to the opposite of that other question. You would initialize your `double[,,]` to whatever size you needed, then start filling in rows with `Marshal.Copy` ([this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146633(v=vs.80).aspx)). You could also marshal over a single double with the same function. Something like this:

```
double[,,] arr = new double[25, 25, 200];
int il = arr.GetLength(0), jl = arr.GetLength(1), kl = arr.GetLength(2);

IntPtr values = DllFoo();

for (int i = 0; i < il; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < jl; j++)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < kl; k++)
        {
            double[] temp = new double[1];
            arr[i,j,k] = Marshal.Copy(values, temp, 1, k + j * jl + k * jl * kl);
        }
    }    
}
```

You can definitely squeeze a lot more performance out of that snippet, but it should still work.

Comment: The first solution will not work for me since the size of the matrix will not be constant. The second one threw an exception (Requested range extends past the end of the array) at the Marshal.Copy line. And I'm sure that I'm passing the correct size values to your function.

Comment: Also, I had to modify it a little, since Marshal.Copy returns void, I assumed that the value supposed to be saved is temp[0], so arr[i,j,k] = temp[0]. Is that right?

Comment: Oh right yeah, that's definitely how it's supposed to be. Wrote all my code directly on SO, so it's never been compiled or anything :P